# Azure API Management - How to add API using powershell with versioning schema "path" and version identifier "v1"

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Import-AzureRmApiManagementApi do not contains option to add versioning schema "path" and version identifier "v1" there exist some other way not using portal ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via the API it will be necessary to create an ApiVersionSet first with the versioning parameters and then reference that ApiVersionSet. The SDK that supports this has just been put into preview https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement/4.0.0-preview The Powershell will follow at a later date. The example/tests of using it can be found here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/270ea2d079e659dd4ba11dce2b3450f23789963e/src/SDKs/ApiManagement/ApiManagement.Tests/ManagementApiTests/ApiRevisionTests.cs

Comment: I think the question was around Powershell not with Resource manager REST API